# References for methods for calculating the confidence interval for Theil-Sen Estimator

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, nonparametric, references

For the Theil-Sen estimator I am aware of two principal methods for obtaining confidence intervals:

- The zyp R-package documentation uses:

> The confidence interval on the slope is calculated using the method defined in (Sen, 1968). The confidence interval on the intercept is computed by taking the standard deviation of the intercepts
>   (sd.i), the z statistic for the given confidence level (z), and the mean (m). The confidence level
>   is then:
>   c(m - z * sd.i, m + z * sd.i)

- Wilcox (2009) proposes to use bootstrapping which makes few assumptions but can be computationally costly.

Can somebody:

1. Provide a link where the method used by R is explained?
2. Tell me what assumption are made by the method used by R?
3. Link to quantitative research into the consequences/sensibility to data violating the assumptions?

Of course I would be equally happy if somebody answered my questions directly rather than providing links.

Comment: Are you sure that isn't Wilcox [1998](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/(SICI)1521-4036(199807)40:3%3C261::AID-BIMJ261%3E3.0.CO;2-V/full)?