# How can bootstrap be used to establish confidence intervals for Theil regression parameters?

Tags: regression, nonparametric, bootstrap, monte-carlo, jackknife

In [References for methods for calculating the confidence interval for Theil-Sen Estimator](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44806/references-for-methods-for-calculating-the-confidence-interval-for-theil-sen-est), we note that Wilcox ([1998](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/(SICI)1521-4036(199807)40:3%3C261::AID-BIMJ261%3E3.0.CO;2-V/full), 2009?) proposed the use of bootstrap as a method for finding confidence intervals for Theil regression of heteroscedastic conditions. There is a practical problem doing this and that is the treatment of ties. That is, since bootstrap is sampling with replacement, it is probable to eventually sample the same point twice leading to an indeterminate slope pair. Thus, we need to either discard indeterminate results or use something else, for example a variant of leave n/2 out.

Q1: How do we resolve the indeterminate bootstrap problem for Theil regression?

Possible answers: Heretofore unspecified correction for ties.
Incomplete Jackknife of n/2 samples (e.g., I have 412 samples, leave out 206 cannot be completely re-sampled as the combination of 412 samples taken 206 at a time is a geological time to completion answer competitive with the age of the universe on my pc. Moreover, leave one out would not be very useful for establishing confidence intervals).

BTW, leave half out appears to work +/- circa 7% on Monte-Carlo simulation of my data. However, that is a far cry from proving that the leave half out approach is valid.

Any clarification would be welcome.

Comment: I am not familiar with the basic Theil-Sen estimator algorithm in practice, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theil%E2%80%93Sen_estimator) says essentially "Theil = median slope $\Delta y/\Delta x$ over all pairs of sample points", while "Sen = median over all pairs of sample points with $\Delta x \neq 0$". So the bootstrap part of the question seems un-needed to encounter the basic problem (actually, since neither description says *distinct* points, the Sen version could *still* have this difficulty). Generalizing Sen would just assign 0 weight to point-pairs with the same point.

Comment: @GeoMatt Sen makes undesirable assumptions concerning the distribution of slopes that I believe to be not useful in the majority of cases, including mine. Sen uses all distinct pairs of sample points, but bootstrap has to have replacement of points without uniqueness to be usable.

Comment: @GeoMatt Indeed, it would seem that the problems with the Sen estimator is what led Wilcox to propose bootstrap in [1998](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/(SICI)1521-4036(199807)40:3%3C261::AID-BIMJ261%3E3.0.CO;2-V/full).

Comment: If you have whatever procedure that allows you to compute a *single* realization of the estimator, then that procedure will take a median over some empirical distribution of *pairs* of points. So why not just do bootstrap resampling on that point-pairs PDF? (vs. drawing each point of a pair independently). In other words you bootstrap the PDF of slopes.

Comment: Anyway, I am not clear on what the underlying "model" for Theil-Sen regression is. For what it's worth, if I care about robustness, I will typically just use a robust residual norm (e.g. an [M-estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares)). If I care about "errors in variables", I will typically use [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares). For both, I'd probably do [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus), but if I needed a well-defined parametric model, I'd probably do a combo, using "TLS" with a robust norm.

Comment: @GeoMatt22 Last comment is off topic, but useful anyway.

Comment: @GeoMatt22 I am not sure that sampling point-pairs to build a PDF will work, one would think so, I'll have to check with simulation. If so, problem solved. Actually, I had considered that but the code was more complicated so I didn't. If it works, your comment should be converted into an answer. I'll let you know how it works out.